# make background images scalable to window

Tags: javascript, html, css

let me think, how can i explain my problem. i have a scrolling page with lots of div layers... one below the other! they background images have resolution of 1920x1080 px! but they should fill the complete background browser window. eg when im scaling the browser window the picture should scale itself.

ive seen a few jquery plugins who do a very good job but its important for me that the backgroundimage is defined in the css, because im using the inview.js and try to create the parallax effect.
is this possible?

thanks ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background-size: cover` for this although it is a CSS3 property and some browsers will not support it.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

**Edit:** A prefixed and fallback solution courtesy of [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: using css3 is okay for me. it works but now ive the problem with gaps between the background images... and i dont know why...

http://i.imagebanana.com/img/wj3z04kc/Bildschirmfoto20130203um13.38.19.png

Comment: Verify that the image actually filling the element. An element highlighting inspector will help you work that out. It could be any number of things if it's not the image (positioning, margins if they're relative).

Comment: thank you, it was my fault because of margins... :) it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
html, body{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Then, to make your image work for super-large displays (ie: multi-screen, etc...), scale it from an `<img>` and set a low z-index.

```
.background{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:0;
}


<img src="background.jpg" class="background">
```

Change `background.jpg` to your background image & put `<img>` tag at the bottom of the page so it loads last.  You may have to play with the z-index if it doesn't display at the right level (ie: covers other elements up)