# How can I stretch my image by height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background from website so if I'll go to mobile it will stretch it by height in center.
Something from that: [large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvQ4x.png) to that [small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYq9l.png)

my code is:

```
    body{
    background-image: url("Tie_logo_shaders.jpg");
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672238/make-background-images-scalable-to-window

Comment: @OrbadiahKrockenberger I did and it works great in small screen, but in large screen it does something like [that](http://imgur.com/a/NzyRL)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```css
.bg-img{
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/27/3e/43/273e43a71854d8359186ecc348370f8d.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
  </div>
</body>
```